# Master Table Node missing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've installed Micrososoft SQL Server 2012 Express. When I launch Managament Studio, I can't view any "table node" on System database..

Is it a bug?

Comment: maybe you don't have any permisssions to see them. Can you use sql server normally?

Comment: I can access to any master table by SQl, however I can't see any of them through Management Studio. Tables Node under Master database is missing..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug as mentioned at following link:
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/773184/ssms-system-databases-node-does-not-show-tables