# Master table node missing , SQL Server 2012 SP1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I've installed Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express with SP1 (with all the "Cumulative Update #6 for SQL Server 2012 SP1")

Can't view any "table node" on System database under “master” in the Management Studio.

Note : there is a post here that point to another link (MS id : 773184), but is confusing.

Appears is a bug "solved" but still the same problem...

Please advice

[image]

[Master Table Node missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591194/master-table-node-missing)

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/773184/ssms-system-databases-node-does-not-show-tables

Comment: What's your exact product version? Maybe there were no major release yet?

Answer (score 1):

SP1 CU#7 is out. Try to update and check.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2894115